# Github for Windows sync issue

Tags: github-for-windows

As of the latest version of Github for Windows (1.0.24), I began having issues merging and syncing repos. I have an enterprise github account.

Here is an example situation, I merge my develop branch into the master, but the commit does not display when viewing the master branch in GFW. Therefore the sync option is not available because GFW believes the code on the local repo and server are in sync.

When I look at the master branch source code, I see the the latest commits from the develop branch that were merged into it are there. GFW does not display any commits EXCEPT when you use the Manage branch option. There you can see the lastest commit is the in the master branch.

Something is out of whack, maybe its me!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, I get the exact same thing from time to time - you're not crazy.
I wish they'd fix it though

Comment: I have been in contact with the dev team and they have acknowledged it as a bug. Hope it gets resolved soon.

Comment: Same issue here. The workaround is to make some meaningless change and than sync.

Comment: Looks like github for windows fixed this issue in release 1.0.26.

Comment: Bug still present in 1.1.0.0 . It would be so simple to force sync on click. Workaround: Click `Tools`, `Open a shell here`, then type `git pull`.